# Resizing the columns width in Windows Form DataGrid when the whole form is resized (.NET 4.0)

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataGrid` with a lot of columns. I've anchored the `DataGrid` so when I resize the whole form it is resized too. Unfortunately the width of the columns remains unchanged and that's not ok. I saw a solution here with setting the last column to `Fill` but that way the more I enlarge the main form the larger the last column gets without resizing the else. I wrote that there's a built in solution for `.NET 4.5` but I'm restricted to `.NET 4.0` so is there any way to resize the width of all my columns keeping the same proportion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want all columns to be of equal width and fill the grid, you could just handle the `Resize` event.

```
    private void dataGridView1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int width = dataGridView1.Width / dataGridView1.ColumnCount;
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            column.Width = width;
    }
```

You may have to make small adjustments, but that's the gist of it.